# View IP's attempting to access FTP?

Tags: ftp, whm

I currently have WHM+CSF set up. I have made it so port 21 is blocked by default, but have whitelisted several IP's so they can access FTP.

My issue is that a third party is attempting to automate FTP uploads, but I have no idea what their IP is so I don't know what to whitelist.

They gave me a list of IP ranges to whitelist, which I have, and it still is not letting them in.

How do I see what IP they are trying to access the FTP from? I checked the logs and it isn't in there...I'm assuming because the server doesn't make logs for IP's that have been blocked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by going into ConfigServer Security & Firewall -> Watch System Logs -> var/log/messages.